# xcode ios- local notification with timer

Tags: ios, xcode, notifications, uilocalnotification

I am using a `UILocalNotification` to schedule a `UIAlertView`, which works just fine.  However, I need to "do something" if the user does not respond to the notification after some time (e.g. 1 minute).  Also, I don't have to use a `UIAlertView` if there is another way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You could start a timer with NSTimer as soon as you display the UIAlertView. When the timer finishes, you could execute the specific action you want. When the user taps one of the buttons in the UIAlertView, you would invalidate the timer.

Quick sample:

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate> {
    UIAlertView *alert;
    NSTimer *timer;
}

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Test" message:@"test" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];

    timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:4 target:self selector:@selector(timerTick:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

    return YES;
}

- (void)timerTick:(NSTimer*)timer
{
    [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:-1 animated:YES];
}

- (void)alertViewCancel:(UIAlertView *)alertView
{
    [timer invalidate];
}

@end
```